# Interact with user-saved placemarks and collections via REST API?

Tags: here-api

I have a Nokia/here.com account which stores severals collections of placemarks. Is there way to use the REST API to interact with these user/account-specific placemarks, like list and update them? If yes, where's the best place to start? Is anybody aware of some example?

Answer (score 1):

We do not have such API at the moment but I sent a follow-up inquiry to the related product team and I will have some more feedback in the coming days.

Otherwise, we do have the Custom Location Extension (CLE) API that could be of interest. Please see:

- Documentation: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/custom-location/topics/overview.html
- REST examples: http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#cls

Comment: I got additional feedback John. The idea of an open Collections API is an excellent one but is not on the roadmap for the coming months. 2015 will likely see improvements in Collections sharing and access so please keep checking www.here.com and 360.here.com for latest updates. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I'd love to see Collections support with access to personal placemarks/favourites.