# Is there a way to access a user's collections via the API?

Tags: here-api

I'm developing an app using the HERE apis.

I was wondering if there's a way to handle this use case

1. User signs up for a HERE account.
2. The user adds a few saved locations, such as "home" and "work" to their collections.
3. The user logs into my app, and authorizes my app.
4. My app can then use locations from the user in my API calls to handle queries such as taking the user to their Home.

I found a really old post about this ([Interact with user-saved placemarks and collections via REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898259/interact-with-user-saved-placemarks-and-collections-via-rest-api)), which mentions that the feature was not coming in 2015 - is such a feature available now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. User signs up for a HERE account.

   - Yes, on [here](https://developer.here.com/)
2. The user adds a few saved locations, such as "home" and "work" to their collections.

   - Yes, on [CLE API Admin](https://enterprise.here.com/#/login) .
3. The user logs into my app, and authorizes my app.

   - User should authorizes your app to set e.g. his apiKey and his layer id
4. My app can then use locations from the user in my API calls to handle queries such as taking the user to their Home.

   - Yes, e.g.: to send [this request to CLE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/custom-location/dev_guide/topics/resource-search-all.html)